# Intermolecular forces between C and Na2O

Tags: intermolecular-forces, reactivity

I was trying to do an experiment called Pharaoh's Serpent and I read that the intermolecular forces between the $\ce{C}$ and the $\ce{Na2O}$ (formed in the thermal decomposition of the $\ce{NaHCO3}$) produced the "serpent" in the experiment, but I can't find what intermolecular force (if there's really one) that is.

What is the structure of this compound?

Here's a link to the experiment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQdK7gaZS0k

edited:

**Here are the reactions that I can think of and I researched :**

1. Sodium bicarbonate decomposition ( with temperature ) :

$$\ce{2NaHCO3 -> Na2CO3  +  CO2 +  H2O}$$

$$\ce{Na2CO3 -> Na2O + CO2}$$

2.Fructose complete combustion:

$$\ce{C12H22O11 + 12O2 -> 12CO2 + 11H2O}$$

3. Fructose incomplete combustion:

$$\ce{C12H22O11 -> 12C + 11H2O}$$

$$\ce{C12H22O11 +6O2 -> 11H2O + 12CO}$$

So , I found that the $\ce{C}$ ( produced in the fructose incomplete combustion) reacts with the $\ce{Na2O}$ ( produced in the sodium bicarbonate decomposition), composing the "body" of the "snake".

Comment: And where do you have Na2O molecules there, I wonder, cause not in solid...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury(II)_thiocyanate#Pharaoh.27s_serpent There's no Na2O or elemental carbon or bicarbonate in this reaction so I'm afraid you deeply confused here and question should be closed as unclear.

Comment: You can do the experiment using NaHCO3 or Mercury(II) thiocyanate. But since Mercury(II) thiocyanate is toxic  , i decided to do using NaHCO3. Heres a link showing how to do the experiment https://melscience.com/en/experiments/sugar-snake/

Comment: Bicarbonates decompose to CO2 not C and still no idea what "intermolecular forces" you want.

Comment: It's sucrose not fructose and combusts completly. I have a feeling that editing won't help here :( I appreciate your responsiveness and additional effort, though.